# Мониторинг запросов мобильного приложения (jmeter) и запуск сценария с среды разработки (jmeter)

Tags: java, eclipse, jmeter

Использую jmeter для мониторинга трафика приложения. Столкнулся с проблемой, мне нужно запускать jmeter и запрос из среды разработки (В моем случаи это Eclipse).
Нужно это для того что бы мне пришел ответ от сервера и в зависимости от ответа выполнялся тот или иной сценарий. Есть идеи предложение как это можно запихнуть в eclipse ?

Comment: как вы себе представляете запуск jmeter ?

Comment: Запуск без gui, мне нужно отправлять и получать запросы на протяжение всей сессии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите зашить в тест какую то сложную логику. Для этой цели может подойти следующий подход.

Вы можете написать собственный сэмлер - класс наследуемый от [`AbstractJavaSamplerClient`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html). В нем есть три интересующих нас метода: `runTest`, `teardownTest`, `setupTest`

Собственно реализуете логику, компилируется, собираете `jar`. Далее созданный артифакт копируете в `${jmeter_home}/lib/` и запускаете приложение. В настройках выбираете **Add->Samplers->Java Request**, где в названии класса записываете название класса реализованного на предыдущем шаге

Выглядить это будет примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ссылку можно узнать на подробное объяснение, того что ты написал ?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/implement-custom-jmeter-samplers

Answer (score 1):

У JMeter имеется [Java API](http://jmeter.apache.org/) с помощью которого вы можете запустить существующий тест используя класс [StandardJMeterEngine](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/engine/StandardJMeterEngine.html) примерно следующим образом

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;

public class RunJMeterTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("/путь/к/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("/путь/к/jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        SaveService.loadProperties();
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/jmeter/bin/test.jmx"));
        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }
        String logFile = "/файл/с/результатами/теста.jtl";
        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```

Не забудьте добавить содержимое папок "lib" и "lib/ext" в [CLASSPATH](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-set-the-classpath-in-eclipse) своего проекта

Более подробную информацию о различных способах запуска JMeter можно найти в статье [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)